# prevent AlertDialog be full screen?

Tags: android, kotlin

My alertDialog is ok in android 8.1.0 but in 4.4.4 is full screen

```
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle)
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.sign_out_message))
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.action_no) { _, _ -> }
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.sign_out) { _, _ ->

    }
    val alertDialog = builder.create()
    alertDialog?.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    alertDialog.show()
```

My style

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Check your dialog style `R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle`

Comment: Please put screenshots of both version

Comment: thank you @Md.Asaduzzaman, I have put AppCompatAlertDialogStyle in v21 style instead of style